# syntax error for my php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php

here is my php code

`echo ("<td><img src='edit.jpg' width='20' alt='Edit' title='EDIT DATA' onClick=\"swipe2('" + . mysql_result($result, $i, 'no'). + '');'style='cursor:pointer;'" ></td>");`

my function

`function swipe2(no) { window.open ( 'edit.php?no='+no,'newwindow') }`

the problem are syntax and also when i click the link the new window by (function) wont open thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

**Replace**

```
onClick=\"swipe2('" + . mysql_result($result, $i, 'no'). + '');
```

**with**

```
onClick=\"swipe2('" . mysql_result($result, $i, 'no'). "');
                      ---------------------------------^--
```

also **replace**

```
style='cursor: pointer;'" ></td>");
```

**with**

```
style='cursor: pointer;'></td>");
----------------------^^^-----
```

you have extra `"` in above code

So your complete code would be.

```
echo ("<td>
    <img src='edit.jpg' width='20' alt='Edit' title='EDIT DATA' 
        onClick=\"swipe2('". mysql_result($result, $i, 'no') ."');
       style='cursor:pointer;'>
</td>");
```

Comment: it has no error now, but now it has no cursor pointer  and still no newwindow open

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
<?php
//replace 0 with your mysql_result call
$result = 0;
echo ("<td><img src=\"edit.jpg\" width=\"20\" alt=\"Edit\" title=\"EDIT DATA\" onClick=\"swipe2(".$result.");\" style=\"cursor:pointer;\" ></td>");
?>
<script>
    function swipe2(no) { window.open ( 'edit.php?no='+no,'newwindow') }
</script>
```

some tips:

- use double quotes for attributes (not required, but more "standard"). So you have to escape them using \"
- try not to put mix function calls with string concatenation. Put the call in a variable, and use the variable in the string. It's easier to read and maintain.
- I removed the quotes in the swipe2(something) called, assuming your result is always a number. If it isn't then you'll have to add quotes ( single might work here better, or escaped double quotes, in which case you might need to escape them and escape the backslash too: \\"